# Fast Fourier Transformation, step where I can't follow the equality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, kalman-filter

I am been this equation but I can't follow how this holds.

Eq1:

$$e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)(N-1)(T/2)}\cdot\frac{(\sin((w-w_k)((NT/2)))}{(\sin((w-w_k)(T/2)}=\frac{1-e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT}}{1-e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T}}$$

As I can see

Eq2:

$$e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)(N-1)(T/2)}={e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}\cdot e^{-j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T/2}} = \frac{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}}{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T/2}}$$

We also know the identity that $\sin(\delta)= \dfrac{e^{j(\delta)}-e^{-j(\delta)}}{2j}$

Therefor I could use this identity to derive

Eq3

$$\frac{(\sin((w-w_k)((NT/2)))}{(\sin((w-w_k)(T/2)} = \frac{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}-e^{-j \left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}}{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T/2}-e^{-j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T/2}}$$

From this I get  Eq2 times Eq3(right hand of equations)

$$\frac{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}}{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T/2}} \cdot \frac{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}-e^{-j \left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT/2}}{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k \right)T/2}-e^{-j\left(\omega -\omega_k \right)T/2}} =$$

$$\frac{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)NT}-1}{e^{j\left(\omega -\omega_k\right)T}-1}$$

Now this means that I have not been able to derive the result as stated in equation 1. 
And I must have done something wrong. Could someone please identify where in my steps I went wrong and how to derive the steps in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$\frac{x-1}{y-1} = \frac{-(1-x)}{-(1-y)}=\frac{1-x}{1-y}$$

Comment: omg no I am truly embarrassed.

Comment: Sometimes, it happens. Don't  worry...